# in hive-site.xml ,"javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" which password should I give?

Tags: hive

In hive-site.xml(hive-0.9.0),I have 2 properties

1) `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName`

2) `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword`

what does these do ?, which username & password should I give ?
are they related to root/mysql ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alongside `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` and `javax.jdo.ConnectionDriver` they are intended to connect to Hive's metastore. Are you planning on using MySQL or another database as metastore? You only need to set these if you're not using Hive's standard metastore (Derby).

An example of how to set up `hive-site.xml` when using MySQL:

```
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<databasename></value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>avax.jdo.ConnectionDriver</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value><your database user></value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value><your database user password></value>
 </property>
```

If you're indeed planning on running another database as metastore don't forget to create a database and run the scripts in `$HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/`.

The easiest to do this latter in my opinion is to first create your database in the MySQL shell then exit the shell and use this command from your shell: `mysql -u <username> -p -h <host> <databasename> < <sql script>`

By the way, I think it's better to create a Hadoop specific database user instead of using your root user.

Comment: javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName,javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword parameters are already present in hive-site.xml,I don't want to use mysql database(but want by default),then should I include above 2 parameters & javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL,javax.jdo.ConnectionDriver in hive-site.xml